# Converting long form data into wide form in SQL or oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a dataset given in the following format
Account Class

[image]

I need to convert it in the following format in Oracle
[image]

How can i do this as its a huge dataset

Answer (score 0):

You may use [PIVOT](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php) clause for this.
But you need to assign each account it's column name within class.
You may use row_number, rank or dense_rank.

```
WITH tab AS
(SELECT 'A1' ACCOUNT, 'C1' CLASS FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'A2' ACCOUNT, 'C2' CLASS FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'A3' ACCOUNT, 'C1' CLASS FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'A4' ACCOUNT, 'C3' CLASS FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'A5' ACCOUNT, 'C3' CLASS FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'A6' ACCOUNT, 'C2' CLASS FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'A7' ACCOUNT, 'C1' CLASS FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'A8' ACCOUNT, 'C4' CLASS FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'A9' ACCOUNT, 'C5' CLASS FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'A10' ACCOUNT, 'C1' CLASS FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'A11' ACCOUNT, 'C2' CLASS FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'A12' ACCOUNT, 'C1' CLASS FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'A13' ACCOUNT, 'C3' CLASS FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'A14' ACCOUNT, 'C3' CLASS FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'A15' ACCOUNT, 'C2' CLASS FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'A16' ACCOUNT, 'C1' CLASS FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'A17' ACCOUNT, 'C1' CLASS FROM dual )
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT CLASS,
               ACCOUNT,
               row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY class ORDER BY account) col_num
          FROM tab)
 PIVOT (MAX(account) FOR col_num IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
```

This example sorts accounts alphabetically (A1, A10, A12, A16, A3, A7,...).
If you need other sorting, it is also not difficult to implement in ORDER BY clause of row_number function.